# FCM for android: popup system notification when app is in background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to show popup for firebase system notification (when app is in background) on the top of screen? I use `setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)` for this to show notifications from `onMessageReceived` in foreground.

I use both `notification` and `data` fields, so I don't have access to received notification in foreground. I've tried setting `priority` to `high` and using notification-only pushes - nothing helps.

Comment: check the doc the behaviour you look for is described here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: Not possible I guess

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is only possible to handle the message in `onMessageReceived` when your app is in background when using a `data` only payload.

When using both `notification` and `data` in your payload,  the expected behavior is that the Android System will handle the notification when the app is in background, regardless of what is the value of your `priority`.

See the official docs on [Handling Android Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#handling_messages) for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I've left only `data` field in payload and showed custom notification with `Notification.Builder` from `onMessageReceived`. First I thought it would be unnecessary code to show notification myself while FCM can do it on its own, but later I found that this way is much more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

If you sent **data** field only in notification, you can handle notification inside the below function

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " +remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }

}
```

Please note that don't include **notification** field in that request

Comment: It's not called in while app is in background. From docs: "When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user taps on the notification."

Comment: Send only data field. Not notification field. If both are send, FCM will automatically show notification. If you send only data field, it will be received in onMessageReceived()