# Firebase Cloud Messaging Notification only shows when I open the "notification tab"

Tags: java, android, push-notification, notifications

So I got push-notifications working with Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging. The only problem now is that the notification doesn't show any alert, only if I pull down the notification drawer that I see it's there.

I've got this part of the code where I think that "popup" feature is added

```
public void displayNotification(String title, String body){
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, Constants.CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body);

        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        if(mNotificationManager != null) {
            mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        }

    }
```

Other problem I have is that when I click the notification, it opens the activity but **doesn't delete** the notification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Foreground pop-up**

Under the builder, you are required to set high or max priority as well as the default notification vibration / sound so that you can see the 'pop-up' window

```
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
.setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL);
```

**Background pop-up**

To achieve background pop-up, you need to fine-tune your FCM payload. If you have both `data` and `notification` in your payload, the pop up cannot be handled by your `displayNotification` method. You will need a `data` only payload.

Google has placed this behavior in the documentation. 
[image]
Reference - [FCM for android: popup system notification when app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315296/fcm-for-android-popup-system-notification-when-app-is-in-background)

**AutoCancel**

For your second issue, add the `setAutoCancel` in your builder

```
.setAutoCancel(true)
```

**Extra note**

For some devices like Xiaomi and Redmi, you need to go to Settings to enable floating notification

[image]

Comment: It fixed the problem where the notification wasn't disappearing but the problem where it wasn't alerting still persists

Comment: you may be interested in the behavior of fcm in background or foreground: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315296/fcm-for-android-popup-system-notification-when-app-is-in-background

Comment: your payload has both notification and data?

Comment: @TiagoVitorino I have updated my answer, please check