# Why my FCM notification are delivering silently and do not pop up?

Tags: php, firebase

I am trying to send push notification to my unity game on android using PHP and FCM.
notifications are getting delivered  to device but silently and not in pop up.
i need to know why?
am I missing something?

I tried replacing Notification key with Data but they nothings works.

```
  function send_notification ($tokens, $message,$title){
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
    $notification= array('title' => $title,'body' => $message);
    $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $tokens,
            'notification' => $notification,
            'priority' => 1
        );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key =xxxxxxxxxxxx',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);           
   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }
   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}
```

I Wanted my notification to pop up.
currently it just gets in notification tray

Comment: what device are you using for testing: android, ios, etc?

Comment: we are testing on multiple android devices

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it works as expected. I see popup only when screen is locked.

This is full list of android-specific features for FCM push https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidNotification

Take a look at this answer [FCM for android: popup system notification when app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42315296/fcm-for-android-popup-system-notification-when-app-is-in-background)

Maybe you should include this functionality directly in your Unity app: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/namespace/firebase/messaging

Comment: for me notifications is coming but did not pop up.
even icon of notification is gray.
i think it should have something to do with android notification channels  but i can not find anything about that in unity

Comment: @DesiMulga all [AndroidConfig is here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#AndroidConfig)