# Firebase push notification is not popup on the screen [Flutter]

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to implement firebase push notifications for a flutter app.

But it appears just as an icon in the status bar. How can i make it pop up?

[image]

I want popup on the screen when notification is received.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
 Future<bool> sendNotification(var userToken, String bodyMessage) async {
 final data = {
  "notification": {
    "body": bodyMessage,
    "title": "Leave Application",
  },
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "id": "1",
    "status": "done"
  },
  "registration_ids": userToken,
 };

 final headers = {
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization':
  'key=<Firebase web key>',
 };

 final response = await http.post(postUrl,
    body: json.encode(data),
    encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'),
    headers: headers);

 if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(response.statusCode.toString());
  print("Working");
  return true;
 } else {
  print(postUrl.toString());
  print(response.statusCode.toString());
  print("Not Working");
  return false;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hey, is your app on the foreground ?

Comment: No, app is not on the foreground.

Comment: have you implemented below callbacks? as mentioned in the docs - https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging

Comment: So you have to write native code for each, android and ios.

Comment: are you also using flutter_local_notifications? these 2 are conflicted to each other, make sure only 1 can be using.

Comment: @JimChiu, No I'am not using  flutter_local_notifications.

Comment: @Jim hi, may i know how you handle for these condition? thank you

Answer (score 15):

All notifications will be sent to **Miscellaneous** channel if `android_channel_id` is not specified in the FCM HTTP API. **Miscellaneous** channel comes with a default level of importance which only has sound but will not pop on screen.

To make the notification pop on screen, you need to **create a notification channel with importance of max/high**. For detailed steps on how to create a notification channel, you may refer to the [Notification Channel Documentation by FlutterFire](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#notification-channels).

After the notification channel is created, you can add the channel id (eg: high_importance_channel) into the FCM HTTP API request body and the notifications that sent to this channel should start to pop on screen when your app is in the background.

```
{
  "notification": {
    "android_channel_id": "high_importance_channel",
    "title": "Notification Title",
    "body": "Notification body ...",
    "sound": "default",
    "priority": "high",
    "time_to_live": 86400,
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
  },
  "data": {
    "post_id": 10000012,
    "type": "NEWS",
  },
  "condition": "'dogs' in topics"
}
```

[image: 1st image]
[image: 2nd image]

Comment: This works perfectly . I am working on C# server side and Xamarin Mobile. THe main point here is we need to create Miscellaneous  channel with Max prioirty so that if server side sent the message it will be delivered to Miscellaneous  channel which changed to Max thats why it will pop up.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem and dug deeper and from what I found you can't achieve what you want in Flutter. Although, you can handle Firebase `onMessageReceived` in Java/Kotlin and then show the notification that you want.

Please refer here: [FCM for android: popup system notification when app is in background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323617/3158312)

Comment: I added the sound in my data payload and set to default, but it still does not head up.

Comment: this is my payload:  DATA='{"notification": {"body": "test chat","title": "test chat"}, "priority": "high", "data": {"click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", "page": "chat", "sound": "default", "numB": "numB", "numA": "numA", "prenomB": "Djiva"}, "to": "userToken"}'
curl https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X POST -d "$DATA" -H "Authorization: key= yourKey"

Comment: Later I'll try to fully reproduce your problem and find an answer.

Comment: @JeevaCanessane Okay, I tried to reproduce the problem and dug deeper and from what I found you can't achieve what you want in Flutter. Although, you can handle Firebase `onMessageReceived` in Java/Kotlin and then show the notification that you want. Please refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42323617/3158312

Answer (score 1):

Create a notification channel with importance of max/high.

```dart
AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
    Random.secure().nextInt(100000).toString(),
    "High Notification Channel",
   importance: Importance.max,
);
AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
    channel.id.toString(),
    channel.name.toString(),
    channelDescription: "Notes App Channel",
    importance: Importance.high,
    priority: Priority.high,
    icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
    ticker: 'ticker',
);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check weather app is in battery optimization mode or not.
If yes remove it from there.

Steps are as follows:
Settings -> Battery -> Battery Optimization -> "Select your App" -> Click on "Don's Optimise"

Thanks.

Comment: my phone is not on economy mode, and it still do not push